# Jenkins Groovy script to execute shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, graphite

I'm using a groovy script to calculate my build duration and publish a metric to Hosted Graphite, from the command line the following curl will result with the intend effect:

```
echo {someMetricHere} | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003
```

However in my groovy script the last step having generated a metric is to run the following:

```
"echo "+ metric +" | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003".execute()
```

Its returning:

Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "|": error=20, Not a directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "|": error=20, Not a directory
    at hudson8814765985646265134.run(hudson8814765985646265134.groovy:27)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
    ... 1 more

I assume the command doesn't understand the "|" part of the command, any suggestions how I can fix this script to run the intended bash? I thought it might be possible to create a .sh file in the workspace but am not sure how.

Pastebin for those wanting to see full script: https://pastebin.com/izaXVucF

Cheers :)

Comment: the pipe `|` is a feature of shell (bash). so if you want to use it start shell with commands and pipes you want...

Comment: I was under the impression I could execute shell commands through groovy, I've no issue running a separate shell step with this command (I'd probably prefer it) however I don't know how to pass the output from this groovy script into that shell step.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

to use pipe `|` try this code:

```groovy
// this command line definitely works under linux:
def cmd = ['/bin/sh',  '-c',  'echo "12345" | grep "23"']
// this one should work for you:
// def cmd = ['/bin/sh',  '-c',  'echo "${metric}" | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003']

cmd.execute().with{
    def output = new StringWriter()
    def error = new StringWriter()
    //wait for process ended and catch stderr and stdout.
    it.waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
    //check there is no error
    println "error=$error"
    println "output=$output"
    println "code=${it.exitValue()}"
}
```

the output:

```groovy
error=
output=12345
code=0
```

Comment: Cheers Daggett, I gave this a go but unfortunately no luck :/ Running the exact same command from the server returns no errors but doesn't seem to actually call the Echo & NC command in the same way. Unsure how to debug this though so might need to find a different approach

Comment: are you in jenkins-pipeline? do you have any error in output? try something simple like : `echo 123 | grep 123`

Comment: @WillBroadbent: i got a similar problem now, could you solve it?

Comment: @mmoossen, i've updated the answer with simpler example. please check if it works for you.

Comment: as an important side note be aware that `def cmd = '/bin/sh -c echo "12345" | grep "23"'` wont work....

Comment: Know of an equivalent when Jenkins is hosted on Windows?

Comment: [ 'cmd', '/c', 'echo 12345 | ...' ]

Answer (score 2):

I think something is wrong with the concatenation you did.

This code should work:

```
"echo ${metric} | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003".execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to achieve this is to use the [Jenkins Job DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#). It features a `shell` command that can be issued from within a given `step`. For example:

```
// execute echo command
job('example-1') {
    steps {
        shell('echo Hello World!')
    }
}

// read file from workspace
job('example-2') {
    steps {
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('build.sh'))
    }
}
```

You can find the reference [here](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-steps-shell).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from great (albeit complex) accepted answer from [daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488427/9993205), here is easy (to remember and type in Jenkins Script UI) way:

```
['/bin/sh', '-c', 'env | grep JAVA_OPTS'].execute().text
```

Scripted pipeline is as easy as
`sh 'env | grep JAVA_OPTS'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass in a variable to a groovy script, you do it using `${variableName}`. Double quotes are not interpreted like the way you think they would, and every compiler treats it in a weird way.

In your case, the below line should help to do the thing you want:

```
sh "echo ${metric} | nc carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003"
```